# How to power a dispenser without powering a hopper below?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

[image]

How can I power that dispenser in the picture without stopping the hopper from transferring items at the same time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Power the dispenser indirectly with a block so that it can't power the hopper.
[image]